# Removing duplicate entries which would exist after insert 

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a small problem with inserting information from one table to other.

For example: from `table A` (can contain ~10 kk entries) to `table B`, tables are identical except `table A` has `DateTimeStamp` which is used to take certain data (boundaries).

So I need to move data from A to B (without `DateTimeStamp`) and remove duplicates from B.

Example:

**Table A**

```
DateTimeStamp | Key | value 
2012-02-03    |  2  | 123
2012-02-03    |  3  | 985
2012-02-03    |  5  | 1584
```

**Table B**

```
Key  | value 
  8  | 45
  3  | 785
  9  | 7457
```

So I need to delete row with `Key = 3` from `Table B` and insert everything else from `Table A`.

Results would be:

```
Key  | value 
  8  | 45
  3  | 985
  9  | 7457
  2  | 123
  5  | 1584
```

Is there elegant way to do this ? Triggers are too slow, and I am looking for solution that wouldn't require temporary table.

SQL Server or SSIS solutions\suggestions are welcome

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server?? 2008 would have the `MERGE` command that would be perfect for this scenario

Comment: 2008, thanks for advice, I will try with MERGE

Comment: OK - see my response for a sample of the MERGE statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server **2008** or newer, you could do this very easily with a single `MERGE` statement - something like this:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.B                -- target table
USING A ON b.Key = a.Key        -- source table and "link" information
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET B.Value = A.Value   -- if "Key" already present in B - update "Value"
WHEN NOT MATCHED                        -- if "Key" not present in B - insert new row
    THEN INSERT(TblKey, TblValue) VALUES(A.TblKey, A.TblValue) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    DELETE                              -- if present in B, but not in A -> remove
;
```

Comment: This will do the thing :) it only once, when 1kk or more entries are used.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

```
-- first delete
delete tableB
from tableB b
inner join tableA a on b.Key = a.Key

-- then insert
insert into tableB
select a.Key, a.Value from tableA a where a.Key not in (select b.Key from tableB b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove Duplicates from table B:

```
    delete FROM tableB Where tableB.Key IN
    (select Key
    from tableA 
    INTERSECT
    select Key
    from tableB)
```

Then, Insert into table B:

```
 insert INTO tableB (Key, Value)
select Key, Value From tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

even though all solutions here presented seem to work, I would really build a package yo deal with a table with 10kk rows.

you can use a oledbsource with the query aF. suggested:

```
select a.Key, a.Value 
from tableA a 
where a.Key not in (select b.Key from tableB b)
```

and send it directly to a oledbdestination pointing to table B